# Prevent leaving app with canDeactivate and intermediate page

Tags: angular, browser-history, angular-router-guards, candeactivate

To my angular app I added Redirect page which is opening first by routing. This page have only one purpose - redirect to home page (`this.router.navigate(['home']);`). To home page I added guard canDeactivate which is checking if nextRoute is redirect page and stop navigation.

```
canDeactivate(
    component: HomePage,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean|UrlTree>|Promise<boolean|UrlTree>|boolean|UrlTree {
    console.log('canDeactivate', currentRoute, currentState, nextState);
    if(!nextState.url.includes('redirect')) {
      return true;
    } else {
      const currentUrl = currentState.url;
      if (this.location.isCurrentPathEqualTo(currentUrl)) {
        this.router.navigate([currentUrl], { skipLocationChange: true });
      } else {
        history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
```

This code works fine only in firefox but not working in chrome or safari. On back button user is not redirected to redirect page but to page before and canDeactivate is not triggered. In chrome or safari it works only if user interact with page (by click etc.). I think there is some problem that redirect page is not pushed to history until user interact with it. Is there any other way I could implement this ?

I need this functionality because I have external authentication to my page and I need to prevent user from go back to login page.